# can the Experience Manager service be setup on the CMS server?

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

Can the Experience Manager service be setup on the CMS server i.e windows server ?

My Content Delivery server is a Linux server and the web application is a Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any issue, as its service exposed over http, i don't see any issue in that. did you try and face any issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to SDL Tridion public documentation portal for 2013 SP1:

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B9941B8E-82DD-4551-92BB-F883DEC54EB2

or directly to the pdf file with prerequisites:

http://sdl.ssl.cdn.sdlmedia.com/file/635543147322472445EY.pdf

where on page 48 it is stated that:

Content Delivery Server Roles run on the following Windows operating systems:

Supported:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)
- Microsoft Windows 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)

Deprecated:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (x64)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I had a very similar implementation with a decoupled web app downstream. You can pass the `XPath` tags XPM requires via `xml/json`. Since Tridion already does this when generating its own markup (as DCP’s) when the content is made available for inline editing by adding the Enable Inline Editing for content TBB to the template.

If the content is currently being published as `XML/JSON` we would need to use the logic from the existing `Enable Inline Editing TBB` to create a new TBB to be applied when the XML/JSON is generated and run as a finishing action.

The purpose of this TBB would be to parse the content, wrap it in the correct XPM tags for the object and resolve any component links (including images) an wrap those as well.  In this way the final content in the brief description field would be fully rendered `HTML` containing the correct XPM markup which can be used as is by the web application - once transformed to `JSON`. So basically, the web app would consume the tags via a web service.